# How do I know which URL is responsible for the call to a route function from inside of it in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

So,

I have several URL's being handled by the same route function in flask like this,

```
@app.route("/<topic>/", methods = ['GET'])
@app.route("/search/<tags>", methods = ['GET'])
@app.route("/bookmarks", methods = ['GET'])
@app.route("/user/<userid>", methods = ['GET'])
@app.route("/direct", methods = ['GET'])
def view_topic(topic = "", userid = "", cno = "", tags = ""):
    return render_template("view.html")
```

How can I know inside of view_topic function which URL call triggered this function call so I could execute my code accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the global flask `request` object. It contains everything you need.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#incoming-request-data

You can either use `request.url` or `request.endpoint`.